# Filtering RDD with CustomObject, Type Mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have this custom Scala object (basically a Java POJO):

```
object CustomObject {

  implicit object Mapper extends JavaBeanColumnMapper[CustomObject]

}


class CustomObject extends Serializable {


  @BeanProperty
  var amount: Option[java.lang.Double] = _

  ...
}
```

In my main class, I've loaded an RDD that contains these CustomObjects.
I am trying to filter them and create a new RDD that contains only the objects that have amount > 5000.

```
val customObjectRDD = sc.objectFile[CustomObject]( "objectFiles" )
val filteredRdd = customObjectRDD.filter( x => x.amount > 5000 )
println( filteredRdd.count() )
```

However, my editor says

> Type Mismatch: Expected: (CustomObject) => Boolean, Actual:
>   (CustomObject) => Any

What do I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` operator is not defined on `Option[Double]`, your filter predicate will need to handle the `Option`:

```
scala> case class A(amount: Option[Double])
defined class A

scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(A(Some(10000d)), A(None),  A(Some(5001d)), A(Some(5000d))))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A] = ParallelCollectionRDD[12] at parallelize at <console>:29

scala> myRDD.filter(_.amount.exists(_ > 5000)).foreach{println}
A(Some(10000.0))
A(Some(5001.0))
```

This assumes that any object with `amount = None` should fail the filter predicate. See [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Option.html#exists(p:A=>Boolean):Boolean) for a definition of `Option.exists`.